# Setting Background property inside VisualState in the ControlTemplate of ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I want to set the `Background` property to `LinearGradientBrush` but it seems it has so many constraints, the [original code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates#listbox-controltemplate-example) was looking like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
        (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                             Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

I thought this might work:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(LinearGradientBrush)">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame.Value>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop/>
                        <GradientStop/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </EasingColorKeyFrame.Value>
            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But it doesn't:

> The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was
>   expected: "Color".
>
> Property 'Value' does not support values of type
>   'GradientStopCollection'.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can't assign a GradientStopCollection to the Value of a EasingColorKeyFrame (because it has to be a Color). It should also be clear that a ColorAnimation can't be used to animate a property of type Brush.

Comment: Yes, I missed this Color vs Linear thing.. So how to set a linear brush and what storyboard should I use?

Comment: Try a ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames with a LinearGradientBrush in a DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.

Comment: With `"(Panel.Background).(LinearGradientBrush)"` as `Storyboard.TargetProperty`?

Comment: No, just `"Background"` (short form of `"(Panel.Background)"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```